# PostgreSQL can't find functions in the same schema

Tags: function, postgresql

Example of the problem:

- Schema name - `schema123`
- Function name = `function123`

Can't find  -> `variable:=function123();`
Can find -> `variable:=schema123.function123()`

Using PostgreSQL 8.4

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're actually doing and trying. I suspect Chris Travers is right about this being a `search_path` issue, but you've provided so little information it's hard to say. What exactly do you mean by "same schema"? Same as ... what?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SET search_path='public, schema123';
```

Then run your function.

A much better approach would be to use the fully qualify the function name with the schema name as in your second example.  That is far less error-prone.

As a note unless you have the schema in the search path functions will not find it.  In Pg 8.4, you have to have complicated  logic inside the stored procedures to set and restore the search.  In 9.2 you can actually set this for the function which may be a good reason to consider upgrading.